# Any good WCF publish/subscribe framework tutorials out there?

Tags: wcf

have been trying to look around the web for a good wcf publish/subscribe framework tutorial but most of it either comes with incomplete instructions or the code doesn't work.

anyone have any good source whereby I can learn more about that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See:

- [What You Need To Know About One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)
- [Design Patterns: List-Based Publish-Subscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx)
- [WCF Implementation of the Publisher/Subscriber Model](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/publisher_subscriber.aspx)
- [Topic-based publish/subscribe design pattern implementation in c#-Part II (Using WCF)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/PubSubUsingWCF.aspx)
- [WCF Publish Subscribe - A Full Example in C#, Step by Step](http://www.anujvarma.com/wcf-and-publish-subscribea-full-example-running-the-client-subscriber/)

And if Azure and the .NET service bus might be an option, also see:

- [Windows Azure – Service Bus Publish/Subscribe Example](http://itechthoughts.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/windows-azure-service-bus-publishsubscribe-example/)
- [Working With The .NET Service Bus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569756.aspx)

Comment: I have taken a look at a few of the above and I realize that some of it includes Managing Persistent Subscribers , whereas some just have a subscribe and a unsubscribe method. Which is a more recommended way of doing it?

Comment: @Thomas: it depends on what you want to do .....

Comment: I plan to just have a publisher(server) send the info to the service, and the service will broadcast the info to all clients. the client would always be subscribed and wont be changing.

Comment: @Thomas: I guess in that scenario, I wouldn't bother with persistent subscribers. Every app should just subscribe to the publisher when it starts up and receives notifications while it's running

Comment: Where can I find tutorials to implement publisher subscriber patterns using .net remoting. I know it's obsolete technology but I want to compare the performance of two systems one based on legacy technology .net remoting and another one with wcf and zero mq