# How to share Model objects between two MVVM WPF applications

Tags: wpf, wcf, .net-remoting

What I'm trying to do is to get two WPF UIs running on two separate computers to share state. I'm thinking to have a service running on one of the two computers hold the MVVM model objects and the two UIs can then be clients of this service, databinding to objects that live in the service. I want to be able to propagate property changes from one UI to the other. So for example, if I have a property bound to a textbox in UIOne and the same property on the same object bound to a label on UITwo, then when I type into UIOne's textbox, the text in UITwo's label updates.

I looked into using WCF for the service, but that looks like it won't work because WCF doesn't allow clients to access object references across service boundaries. And the simplest way I can imagine propagating INotifyPropertyChanged between UIs is by sharing the object by reference. So then I looked at .NET Remoting and it looks like it will allow you to share a .NET object between AppDomains.

But now I'm confused because I thought WCF replaces Remoting.

1. Am I misunderstanding how Remoting shares objects by reference? Would databinding to a .NET remoting object work the way I'm planning?
2. Does WCF really replace Remoting? Is there a way to use WCF to share an object between clients?  I don't want to start using a "legacy" technology if the new one will work for me.
3. Is there a third option I should be considering?

Comment: Yes, WCF replaces .NET Remoting.  You might want to take a look at the publish-subscribe model (which can be implemented in WCF).

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8193562/745969.  It has some links for publish-subscribe with WCF.

Comment: Essentially in your case, the publisher would be the WCF service, and the subscribers would be the WPF applications.