# Create a calendar server to publish events to subscribers

Tags: c#, calendar

We are looking to create a calendar service/server of sorts that allows users to subscribe to it, and as we add new events to the calendar it should update on theirs (push style).  Ideally this should work on mobile calendar programs (native only)

I Google check suggested creating a public ICS file that users can subscribe to, however I'm not sure how supported this is.

Is their a calendar push type RFC format out there?

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

We are using .Net (4.5)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good WCF publish/subscribe framework tutorials out there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193518/any-good-wcf-publish-subscribe-framework-tutorials-out-there)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The mentioned article is specific to publish/subscribe technology, I need something more specific to calendars and supported sync standards.